# Unable to find page elements with Behat / Mink using Selenium 3.5.x

Tags: selenium, xpath, behat, mink

I am working on setting up behavioral tests for our current website. I have used Behat in the past with Selenium standalone server and now have updated to the latest Behat 3 and Selenium 3.5. I am having a multitude of issues though. Using Selenium 3.5 I cannot get xpath selectors to work at all. It is not able to find elements by id, name, class etc. With Selenium 3.4.x it seems to work fine but I cannot get button presses to work. I receive this error:

```
Then I click button "loginBtn"                                                              # FeatureContext::iClickButton()
  mouseMoveTo
  Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
  System info: host: 'matt-VirtualBox', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-59-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
  Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver (WebDriver\Exception\UnknownCommand)
```

This seems to be something that was fixed in 3.5.x with enablePassThrough set to true. Here is my behat.yml configuration.

```
default:
suites:
    default:
        contexts:
            - FeatureContext:
                screenshots_path: '%paths.base%/screenshots/firefox/'
extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
        base_url:  'http://localhost:8080/customer_portal/'
        default_session: selenium2
        browser_name: 'firefox'
        selenium2:
            browser: 'firefox'
            capabilities:
                browserName: 'firefox'
                browser: 'firefox'
                version: ''
            wd_host: 'localhost:5555/wd/hub'
```

And inside of my composer.json file

```
{
"require": {
    "behat/behat": "3.*@stable",
    "behat/mink": "1.7.*@stable",
    "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "@stable",
    "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "@stable",
    "behat/mink-extension": "@stable",
        "phpmd/phpmd" : "@stable"
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin/"
}
```

}

I am using Firefox 55 and geckodriver v18. Has anyone successfully configured selenium to work with Behat 3 and Firefox?

Comment: Can you share the implementation for `I click button "loginBtn"`?

Comment: Here is my implementation:    `/**
     * @Then /^I click button "([^"]*)"$/
     */
    public function iClickButton($button)
    {
        $page = $this->getSession()->getPage();
        $buttonElement = $page->findById($button);
        $buttonElement->click();
    }` Not that I still get this issue with the "I press button" and "I should see" built in functions.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an issue from Selenium. I also have the issue when working with FF and could not get the Element clicked.

Comment: Just tested configuration on chrome and its working with no issues. Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

mouseMoveTo error is well known issue when using selenium3. This error happens only for firefox browser with gecko driver. To fix this issue you can use chrome or update the MinkSelenium2Driver library. Should be master branch of MinkSelenium2Driver which requires behat/mink: ~1.7@dev. Here is the point of the problem MinkSelenium2Driver So if its ok for you to use all the latest behat versions, then composer.json could looks like this:

```
"require": {
    "behat/behat": "v3.3.1",
    "behat/mink": "v1.7.1",
    "behat/mink-extension": "v2.2",
    "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "dev-master",
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated my composer file. I am now receiving this error when I try to run Firefox (v55) with selenium 3.5.3 "Could not open connection: TypeError: Given browserVersion [object String] "9", but current version is [object String] "55.0.2"

Comment: try to update your `capabilities` parameter in `behat.yml` under `selenium2` with one more value `browserVersion = ''`

Comment: you get this error because browserVersion 9 is a default parameter in MinkSelenium2Driver here is [github link](https://github.com/Behat/MinkSelenium2Driver/blob/master/src/Behat/Mink/Driver/Selenium2Driver.php#L182)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm making some progress but after running it I have the same xpath selector issue. This does not happen on Chrome which works successfully. The error is: `When I fill in "j_username" with "test@test.com"  # FeatureContext::fillField()
      Form field with id|name|label|value|placeholder "j_username" not found. (Behat\Mink\Exception\ElementNotFoundException)`

Comment: thats a different error, and not related to the original issue. now it is even different place `fillField ` please check if `j_username` really on the page and you see it in that moment

Comment: you can also vote and confirm if this answer is acceptable for you. thanks!

Comment: The fillField issue is related to the xpath issue I was originally having. Selenium 3.5.x I have xpath issues and 3.4.x I have button click issues. Unfortunately I am back at square one with FireFox.